# C# Showing number of Times Checkbox/RadioBox has been Selected

Tags: c#, checkbox

I'm making an application that calculates a total based on checkboxes and radiobuttons selected. But then I want to see how many of each were selected in another Form or messagebox as a summary feature.

Example

```
User 1 selects: RadioButton 1 and Checkbox 1 and 2,

User 2 selects: radiobox 2 and Checkbox 2

User 3 selects RadioBox 1 and Checkbox 2
```

Summary Results

```
RB1= 2

RB2= 1

CB1= 1 

CB2= 2
```

Does anyone know what the code is to count how many times the CB and RB have been selected?

my code so far

```
   {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    const int Lunch = 25;
    const int Early = 40;
    const int Late = 40;
    const int Table = 10;
    const int Waiter = 20;

    int Meal;
    int Mealprice;
    int Extras;
    const int TotalLunch = 1;
    int TotalEarly = 1;
    int TotalLate = 1;
    int TotalWaiters = 1;
    int TotalTables = 1;

    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Quantity; 
        int Finalprice;

        if (lunchRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
           Meal = Lunch;
           TotalLunch.ToString();
        }
        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked && waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Waiter + Table;
            TotalWaiters.ToString();
            TotalTables.ToString();
        }
        else if (waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Waiter;
            TotalWaiters.ToString();
        }
        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Table;
            TotalTables.ToString();
        }

        //Early Evening Meal
        if (earlyEveningRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            Meal = Early;
            TotalEarly.ToString();
        }

        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked && waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
           Extras = Table + Waiter;
           TotalWaiters.ToString();
           TotalTables.ToString();
        }
        else if (waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Waiter;
            TotalWaiters.ToString();
        }
        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Table;
            TotalTables.ToString();
        }

        //Late evening options
        if (lateEveningRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            Meal = Late;
            TotalLate.ToString();
        }

        //Late Evening, Corner table and Dedicated waiter selected.
        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked && waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Table + Waiter;
            TotalWaiters.ToString();
            TotalTables.ToString();
        }

        //Late Evening and Dedicated waiter selected.
        else if (waiterCheckBox.Checked)
        {
           Extras = Waiter;
           TotalWaiters.ToString();
        }

        //Late Evening and Corner Table
        else if (tableCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            Extras = Table;
            TotalTables.ToString();
        }

        try
        {
            Quantity = int.Parse(guestTextBox.Text);
            Mealprice = (Meal * Quantity);
            Finalprice = (Mealprice + Extras);
            finalAmountLabel.Text = Finalprice.ToString("C");

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a quantity in numerical form","Quantity Error!");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing native that will track how many times anything has been clicked.  You will need to hook up OnClick events and track each one in code.

Comment: it would be appropriate if you post it as a comment. Thx

Comment: It appears you've hooked up the final button click, but none of the events when a checkbox or radio button is changed.  If you are using Windows Forms, when you select the checkbox on the designer, in properties you can see all the valid events.  You'll probably want "OnClick".  When it's clicked, add 1 to the specific counter.